# OLEDB Cannot load data from excel after publishing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, excel, oledb

I am using OLEDb to load table from a local `.xls` file in `C# .Net`. 
The table is loaded and showed correctly when I view the webpage `"View in Browser"`. But when I publish, the table is not shown on the webpage (URL that I publish to) but other parts of the webpage are shown correctly.
Is there a reason why the excel file can be loaded when debugging but cannot load when published? 
Here is the code in C# that load the Excel:

```
strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=//Dfs.local/I/Test Copy.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=False;IMEX=1'";
OleDbConnection OleConn = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
OleConn.Open();
String sql1 = "SELECT * FROM  [Sheet1$]";
OleDbDataAdapter OleDaExcel1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql1, OleConn);
```

My first idea was that the excel spreadsheet could not be access by webpage. But I have another link on the webpage that would open this excel when clicked. And it's working on the webpage after publishing.
Here is the code for the link:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"> 
 Out = '<a href="file://Dfs.local/I/Test Copy.xls">Report<\/a>';
 document.writeln(Out);
</script>
```

I tried many different ways of publishing but could still not load the excel table when opening from URL.

Please help! 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Local file links only work in Internet Explorer and not Chrome or Firefox.
2. When published, the web server runs under a different UserID than the person looking at the web page. Ensure THAT process has proper access/permissions to the excel output file and directory/share. (Typically this account is called W3SVC.)

Comment: Yes I am using Internet Explorer. Any idea what other reason it might be? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the space in the filename.

Comment: After removing the space in the filename as well as changing the filename in the code, the problem still exist... all right in visual studio but nothing on published webpage...

Comment: Does the output file exist? If so, does it have permissions such that the user can access the file? How about the folder permissions and the share permissions?

Comment: The webpage also contains a link to the exact excel file that I am extracting data from. And the excel file can be opened from this link on the published webpage. So I think the file/folder has the permission for access to the user.

Comment: The web server runs under a different userid than the person looking at the web page.  Does THAT process have proper access/permissions to the excel output file and directory/share? Typically this account is called W3SVC.